# How can I route the root of a Rails app to a specific controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have a path that is 'localhost:3000/boards'. So for example 'boards/new', 'boards/1', etc. How can I route that all to root. So I could just do 'localhost:3000/new', 'localhost:3000/1' and it would route to 'boards'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `resources :board, path: "/"` in config/routes.rb